# Is BackgroundWorker suitable for long-running operation?

Tags: .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

any idea suggestion about BGW for long-running operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is :). There is nothing inherently wrong in having long-running operations in a BackgroundWorker or a ThreadPool... if there are deadlocks in the code because of long-running operations, then there is something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: allow your operation to cancel.  BGW allows for this by setting a bool property.  You need to periodically check this property in your DoWork method.